# How to lock GetUserProfileByName value when InfoPath form was submitted

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, user-profile-service

I have created InfoPath form that collects information from the user (name, department, manager etc...) using `GetUserProfileByName` method. I have also created a workflow for this form so that once it is submitted, it will send an email to his manager to approve this form.

While workflow is working fine, every time the manager open the form, his data is populated on the field instead of submitter's (Obvious since it will collect data from logged-on user). Another field that is not using `GetUserProfileByName` method was not affected.

Is there a way to preserve the value once the form was submitted?
[image: Rule on Form Load]

Comment: You need to NOT use the current user when the form is opened by the manager.

Comment: Yes that's the idea, any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for this.

I created hidden field **Person** that store value from **ObserverName** field.

Then i created rule on Form Load that check if **Created By** field is NOT blank, it will not query for data connection then set **ObserverName** field with value from **Person**.

I chose **Created By** field because it sure contain value after the form have been submitted though you can choose any other non-blank field.

Answer (score 2):

Create a rule that checks if the value is blank before fetching the User Name. Then when the manager opens the forms the value will be present and your code will detect and not change the value.

Comment: When I created rule on Form Load that when User Name field ( autoObserverName in my instance) IS BLANK, it is still retrieving manager's value.  Strangely, when I set condition of User Name field IS NOT BLANK, both submitter's and manager's value are not populated. I have included the screenshot on original post.

Comment: After querying the data, are you setting the value of autoObserverName?

Comment: Which value are you referring to? I set the field's value when `Name="PreferredName"`. If you're talking about Set Sample Value in Data Connection Wizard then no i didn't set any value to it.